# Добавить дисковой памяти в Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dual-boot

У меня стоит на данный момент две ОC: Windows и Ubuntu. Дело в том что сейчас понадобилось увеличить размер пространства моей ОС Ubuntu. 
И собственно вопрос как безболезненно это возможно сделать, чтобы не повредить файлы.

Есть идея: в ОС Windows опять же взять нужное кол-во пространства с диска D скажем, у меня он не системный) и попробовать увеличить диск на которой стоит Ubuntu. Пройдёт ли такого рода авантюра?

> lsblk
>   NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
>   sda              8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
>   ├─sda1           8:1    0   500M  0 part  /boot/efi
>   ├─sda2           8:2    0    40M  0 part
>   ├─sda3           8:3    0   128M  0 part
>   ├─sda4           8:4    0   750M  0 part
>   ├─sda5           8:5    0 469.9G  0 part
>   ├─sda6           8:6    0 403.7G  0 part
>   ├─sda7           8:7    0  41.2G  0 part  /
>   ├─sda8           8:8    0   450M  0 part
>   ├─sda9           8:9    0   7.2G  0 part
>   └─sda10          8:10   0   7.6G  0 part
>     └─cryptswap1 252:0    0   7.6G  0 crypt [SWAP]
>
> mount
>   sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
>   proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
>   udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4024576k,nr_inodes=1006144,mode=755)
>   devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
>   tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=808836k,mode=755)
>   /dev/sda7 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
>   securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
>   tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
>   tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
>   tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
>   pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
>   efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
>   cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
>   systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=24,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
>   mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
>   debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
>   hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
>   fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
>   /dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
>   binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
>   tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=808836k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
>   /home/.ecryptfs/morozov/.Private on /home/morozov type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=d8c962395ff64430,ecryptfs_sig=ae3e62a5c7951162,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
>   gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)

Comment: Пойдет. но для начала фрагментацию запусти на диске `D`. 
Необязательно, чтобы `/home` лежал на том же томе, что и `/`. так что на будущее можно отделить `/home` от основного тома

Comment: Какую файловую систему выбирали при установке Ubuntu? Ставили ли LVM? Стоит дополнить вопрос выводом команд "lsblk" и "mount".

Comment: тебе надо с LiveCD загрузиться, запустить gParted и расширять том. возможно, новые ОС умеют на лету менять размер тома

Comment: @Tihon /dev/sda1              vfat        507904    29752    478152   6% /boot/efi
 не уверен что это то что вы уточнили.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator то есть другими словами при переносе /home в другой раздел у меня всё сохраниться, единственное что моя ОС будет на другом диске? или я не совсем так понял.

Comment: @Morozov не сохраниться. это при установке указываются точки монтирования. и в будущем ты переустанавливаешь ОС, не затрагивая свои файлы

Comment: @Morozov, открой в Ubuntu терминал и напиши сначала "lsblk", а потом "mount". Вывод терминала - добавь в вопрос.

Comment: @Tihon обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала забэкапить нужные тебе данные

1. Сделать дефрагментацию раздела
2. загрузиться с `LiveCD`
3. Запустить gparted
4. Выбрать диск и сменить размер(ПКМ -> resize)
5. Нажать применить (apply) и ждать завершения процесса
6. перезагрузиться без  `LiveCD`

Comment: Для LVM - не работает :Р
Для ext4/XFS - можно увеличить размер прямо в ubuntu и без перезагрузки.

Answer (score 1):

При подобных действиях всегда есть вероятность потери данных - делайте резервную копию.

В Windows.

1. Делаете дефрагментацию диска.
2. Открываете от администратора "diskmgmt.msc"
3. Выбираете нужный том. Щелкаете по нему ПКМ - "сжать том". Сжимаете до нужного размера.

В Ubuntu.

1. В терминале от root/sudo: "apt-get update && apt-get install -y gparted".
2. От root/sudo: gparted.
3. Смещаем разделы sda5, sda6, sda7 так, чтобы оставалось неразмеченное место после раздела sda7 (его мы будем расширять). Применяем.
4. Расширяем раздел sda7. Применяем.
5. PROFIT.

Answer (score 1):

После прочитанных ответов, попробовал начать решать проблему.

Итак, по порядку:

1. Зашёл в Windows - управление дисками.
2. Выбрал диск, который можно было сжать. Сжал  его до нужных мне размеров.

Дальнейшие действия:

3. Зашёл в терминал ОС Ubuntu, прописал `sudo su` для получения root'a.
4. после чего воспользовался командой apt-get update && apt-get install -y gparted.

После чего запустился собственно сам gparted, в котором наглядно было показана схема распределения моих дисков. 
Увы, если ваше свободное место располагается **слева** от репозитория который вы хотите увеличить, то у вас ничего не выйдет. И максимальный resize будет равен изначальному объёма данного репозитория.

Поэтому записав на флешку LiveCD(не важно какой версии*) и зайдя в установщик, опять же установил gparted. После чего получилось перенести мой репозиторий с ОС в свободное место(которое раннее выделил).

Все вроде бы как получилось и ничего не слетело.

*Дополнил данный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/605618/211117), возможны частные случаи, как скажем мой.*

Comment: Если свободное место слева от раздела, то нужно переместить раздел. Всё возможно :)

Comment: @Tihon Хм, не нашёл подобной опции.